# Loading an external .htm file into a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I got this code

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.ajax') .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content').load( 'file.htm' )
    })
})
</script>
```

html:

```
<a href="file.htm" class="ajax">Link</a>
```

it works perfectly in firefox, but nothing happens when I click the link in chrome and IE simply opens a new window with the file. any advice?

Comment: It looks like it should work fine in the other browsers as well. I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Your posted code works on Chrome, so I'm guessing you didn't post your whole code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading an external .htm file to a div with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281204/loading-an-external-htm-file-to-a-div-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a coder of any sort, and I know there is more than one way to make this work.
This is what worked for me for MY situation.
I had a working site but with A LOT of code / DIV content all in one page and I wanted to clean that up.
I hope this Helps someone else!

I have been searching for this solution for quite some time and I have run across many examples of how it can work in different instances.
My scenario was as follows:
I have a photography website that uses a series of DIV tags containing the various "pages" so to speak of the site.
These were all set as:
    `<div id="DivId" style="display:none"></div>`
The following script in the head of the page:

```
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function () {
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
```

```
});
</script>
```

and called using the anchor links like this:
    `<a href="" name="home">HOME</a>`
Where name was the name of the DIV to be called.
Please note the DIV will be called inside the parent container DIV.
Lastly and most importantly for this particular question and scenario, the DIV were all placed on the page as shown above.
Each div content was created just as if it were within the DIV tags but minus the opening and closing DIV tags and then saved as a separate .txt file, and called by placing this is the head of the parent page:
    `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js">`
and

```
    
    $(document).ready(function() { // this runs as soon as the page is ready (DOM is loaded)
        $("#DivName") // selecting "div" (you can also select the element by its id or class like in css )
        .load("PathToFile.txt");// load in the file specified
        $("#AnotherDiv").load("AnotherFile.txt");// Additional DIV can be added to populate DIVs on th eparent page.
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Change the link to `href="#"` or `"javascript:void(0);return false;"`

```
<a class='ajax' href='#'>...</a>
```

The loading logic is all in your ajax call. But, you have also a link which points to the file, too.
So, it seems that some browsers give different priorities on how the click is handled.

Anyway, links that do something other than changing page (f.ex. executing js) shouldn't have an explicit HREF attribute other than something that "does nothing" (like above)

Comment: if I change it like you said, nothing happens in both chrome and IE :( firefox still going strong though ...

Comment: The problem is NOT in the href of the link. The prevetDefault call should have stop it from loading. IMO the inner function is not called because when the script runs the DOM is not yet loaded ($('.ajax') = []).

Comment: yea, with that firefox stops working too.. I have a <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> before the upper mentioned - could this have anything to do with it ?

Comment: @MadsFriis That's true, but I wasn't talking about **not having** an href link at all: "*shouldn't have an explicit HREF attribute OTHER THAN something that "does nothing"*"

Comment: @nemo `preventDefault` as far as I know has some bugs and quirks. I still think my answer is appropriate.

Comment: @MadsFriis Have you tried with `href='javascript:void(0);'` and removing `preventDefault` in the code? Or using THIS lice of code: `event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;`

Comment: **For downvoters**: please explain downvote, thanks :) Useful for me and all the readers.

Comment: -1 answer goes totally against principals of progressive enhancement... if javascript disabled correct url should open. Also, jQuery click handler is certainly cross browser compliant as is use of preventDefault

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the explanation. This means that preventDefault's behaviour is overridden and made cross browser-compliant? Also, what if *it is* really a buggy and browser-dependant behaviour? In thast case progressive enhancement would be impossible.

Comment: @Cranio I think you are looking for reasons the OP code doesn't work. There is nothing wrong with it, problem likely lies elsewhere. `event.preventDefault()` is part of jQuery API. API is well tested cross browser so not sure what "buggy" issue you are referring to. Sounds like guessing about issues that likely don't exist

Comment: @charlietfl No, I actually found evidence of buggy behaviour of preventDefault(). What I was curious to know was if JQuery's implementation wrapped it with its own preventDefault() in a browser-compatible way.

Comment: @Cranio I don't buy the buggy issue, only thing would make it buggy would be error thrown prior to it being called, or bubbling problem if propagation was being prevented

Answer (score -3):

I believe the problem is that the script loads before the document is loaded.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.ajax').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content').load( 'file.htm' )
    });
});
```

I am not sure, but i can not see any other problem.

Comment: **-1** - `$(func)`, which the OP is already using, is equivalent to `$(document).ready(func)`.